# 'Wrong password' message won't display anymore - Adminlte3

Tags: php, laravel, adminlte

I am using admittle3 on a system made with Laravel 9 and I have a problem when logging in; If I don't put anything in the password it does bring me the error that it's empty, but if I type the wrong password it doesn't bring me any error back. In the same way, the @crsf is not working (error 419) although it is in the code, but only in the login.

Everything used to work, but some time back it stopped and I'm not sure why.

I tried what is mentioned in [this link](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/issues/972) but it is an older version than the one I currently have, which is:

```
"jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte": "^3.9"
```

My login.blade.php has almost no changes:

```
@extends('adminlte::auth.auth-page', ['auth_type' => 'login'])

@section('adminlte_css_pre')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css') }}">
@stop

@php( $login_url = View::getSection('login_url') ?? config('adminlte.login_url', 'login') )
@php( $register_url = View::getSection('register_url') ?? config('adminlte.register_url', 'register') )
@php( $password_reset_url = View::getSection('password_reset_url') ?? config('adminlte.password_reset_url', 'password/reset') )

@if (config('adminlte.use_route_url', false))
    @php( $login_url = $login_url ? route($login_url) : '' )
    @php( $register_url = $register_url ? route($register_url) : '' )
    @php( $password_reset_url = $password_reset_url ? route($password_reset_url) : '' )
@else
    @php( $login_url = $login_url ? url($login_url) : '' )
    @php( $register_url = $register_url ? url($register_url) : '' )
    @php( $password_reset_url = $password_reset_url ? url($password_reset_url) : '' )
@endif

@section('auth_header', __('adminlte::adminlte.login_message'))

@section('auth_body')
    <form action="{{ $login_url }}" method="post">
        @csrf

        {{-- Email field --}}
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" id="login" name="login" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror"
                   value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="Usuario" autofocus>

            <div class="input-group-append">
                <div class="input-group-text">
                    <span class="fas fa-envelope {{ config('adminlte.classes_auth_icon', '') }}"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            @error('email')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>

        {{-- Password field --}}
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror"
                   placeholder="{{ __('adminlte::adminlte.password') }}">

            <div class="input-group-append">
                <div class="input-group-text">
                    <span class="fas fa-lock {{ config('adminlte.classes_auth_icon', '') }}"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            @error('password')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>

        {{-- Login field --}}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-7">
                <div class="icheck-primary" title="{{ __('adminlte::adminlte.remember_me_hint') }}">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                    <label for="remember">
                        {{ __('adminlte::adminlte.remember_me') }}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-5">
                <button type=submit class="btn btn-block {{ config('adminlte.classes_auth_btn', 'btn-flat btn-primary') }}">
                    <span class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></span>
                    {{ __('adminlte::adminlte.sign_in') }}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    </form>
@stop
```

I'm not really sure what to do; I tried uninstalling and installing again but it also didn't work. What can I do?

Comment: Go start your debugging process step by step. Go to the place where you're supposed to receive the POST of your form. `dd($request->all());` also post part of the function including the arguments (is there a form request?) Always update your original question with more information